# Sending data from a button inside a repeater control to code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a button inside a repeater control, and I need to send some identifying information from the button to the onClick event so I know which ID has been clicked.  My asp.net code (in part) looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="bevelBox"><h3><b><%#Eval("AlbumName") %> Photo Gallery</b></h3></div>

    <asp:Repeater ID="PhotoRepeater" runat="server" onitemcommand="PhotoRepeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="PhotoRepeater_DataBinding">
        <HeaderTemplate>  

            <div class="bevelBox">
                <Table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:160px"><h3>Concert Photo</h3></td>
                        <td style="width:535px"></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnAddPhoto" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddPhoto_Click" Text="Add Yours" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AlbumID") %>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </Table>
        </div>
```

Someone told me I could use the CommandArgument command to get this data to the code-behind.

On the C# side, I have this:

```
protected void btnAddPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string ggg = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
    mdlAddPhoto.Enabled = true;
    mdlAddPhoto.Show();
}
```

I put a break point on the "string gggg" line, just to see what is being passed back.  There's nothing indicating the <%#Eval("AlbumID") %> is being passed back.

Can anyone tell me how I can get this ID data passed back to the C# side?

Comment: As @ggarciasoft says, you're working with the HeaderTemplate, not an item template, is that intentional?

Comment: You cannot bind `Eval` in the header, only a fixed `CommandArgument` will work.

Comment: Yes.  Each header row relates to a specific AlbumID.  And when I display the photos, they have to be associated with a specific AlbumID to get in the correct repeater (I'm actually using a nested repeater; the top level separates by AlbumID and then the inner repeater displays all the photos associated with that AlbumID).